# How to zoom in Firefox on a MacBook Pro

Tags: firefox, macbook, zoom

To zoom in on Firefox on my PC, I hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and move the mouse wheel up. When I try to do this on my MacBook Pro, it zooms in everything, not just what's inside Firefox.

How can I use the zoom in Firefox on a MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your 2 finger for zooming Firefox inside.

Or use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> for zooming in.

And <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> for zooming out.

Answer (score 2):

Moving the mouse wheel up and down while holding both `Ctrl` and `Cmd` keys will let you zoom in and out of the Firefox window, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Other people answered how to do it in Firefox, but if anyone who comes upon this page is curious why the entire screen zoomed on a mac when using `Control`-`scroll`, it's an accessibility function built into macOS called "Zoom". You can enable/disable/configure the feature in System Preferences in the "Accessibility" panel.